# If L2-Regularization includes no bias, why do many images show a circle as the constraint region?

Tags: regularization, ridge-regression, constrained-optimization

I got a little bit (massively, to be honest), confused by the following apparent misconceptions I have learned recently.
Looking for information about L2-Regularization, the following image is one of the most popular ones:

[image]

Often, the following, or similar, notes are written below the image:
The solid blue area is the constraint region $\beta_1^2 + \beta_2^2 \leq t^2 $.
Now, introducing the Lagrangian notation, we would add the following term to some loss function:

$\lambda(\beta_1^2 + \beta_2^2 - t^2) $

However, the $t^2$ is always omitted in any textbook I have read. To me, that would imply that we assume a constraint region with $\beta_1^2 + \beta_2^2 \leq 0 $.
Then the constraint region would actually just be a point though, so some where I am clearly mistaken in my logic.

Where does the constraint region actually appear in the loss function?

Comment: You seem to be invoking an unusual concept of the Lagrange multiplier technique.  The boundary of the constraint region remains the zero set of $\beta_1^2+\beta_2^2-t^2;$ all that has happened is the subtraction of the constant $t^2$ from both sides of the original equation.

Comment: If I understand your comment correctly, I still do not understand why that $t^2$ is never included in the penalty term with L2 Regularization.

Comment: Pick any value of $t$ you like and stick it into the penalty term.  How would that change the solution?

Comment: I see, when optimizing the parameters that term simply vanishes. But that parameter $t$ should play a role somewhere when minimizing a loss function?

Comment: I think you are confusing two different formulations see https://hastie.su.domains/Papers/ESLII.pdf page 63. equations 3.41 and 3.42. the $\lambda$ is in one to one correspondence with the $t^2$ they are related by KKT https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions